# Composer: How to install dependencies recursively automatically?

Tags: composer-php, require

In using composer require to install packages / using composer install with `composer.json`, I run into the following problem:

> "**A**" requires "**B**". After adding "**B**" and composer install
>   again:
>
> "**B**" requires "**C**". After adding "**C**" and composer install
>   again:
>
> "**C**" requires "**D**". After adding "**D**" and composer install
>   again:

---

I am pretty sure I am missing something, or it would be the worst ever design when the dependency chain is long.

How do I make the composer automatically install all missing dependencies for installing **"A"** recursively, instead of loading for like 2-3 minutes each round only to tell me something is missing again, or there are better ways to install dependencies?

Update:
Runs into the following error when using "update":

> Installation request for illuminate/session 5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.2, v5.6.3, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].

How do I install illuminate/session 5.6.* before I install illuminate/session 5.6.* so that I can be able to install illuminate/session 5.6.*? Am I missing a time machine?

Comment: Composer does do that, probably you did not run `composer update`, but only `composer install`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have tried update as well, but it would still stop at some missing packages, while it seems to travel further automatically.

Comment: If you add your package `A` to the `composer.json` and run `composer update`, it will recalculate the dependencies. If that does not work, please add realistic data to your question, including the `composer.json` and the exact messages

Comment: you should add at least your command and the full error message. what you posted as error is no error, just a fact of which versions satisfy your version constraint

Answer (score 5):

If you want to update a package that also updates a dependency you have installed, you should probably pass the argument `--with-dependencies`

For example `composer update vendor/package --with-dependencies`

Comment: Is it relatively safe to do this, or is updating so many dependencies likely to break an application?

Answer (score 0):

For composer 1:

```
composer update vendor/package --update-with-all-dependencies
```